# Make it clear a self-delete vote isn't a "vote", it's just deleting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, vote-to-delete

A sensitive issue erupted recently and part of the problem was a user didn't realize the "delete" button was binding, because they're presented with this dialog when they click "delete":

[image]

It seems they interpreted this as "it's just a vote, it won't happen immediately" and defaced their question's text rather than clicking Okay. But it's not really a "vote" in practical terms, it *would* have been deleted, saving everyone some grief.

Sure, to the database/system it's a binding "vote" but the user doesn't care. You're not voting, you're deleting, and it's needlessly confusing. Just change the text to "Delete this post?" when it's the original poster casting a binding delete vote on their own content. It's also kinda dumb that I get this as a mod, when I don't "vote" either, I just delete, but I'm more concerned about newer/less experienced users being confused.

Comment: I think this is an excellent feature to have. I have seen several posts that I think should have been deleted.

Comment: I vote to agree.

Comment: I've  been caught by this before recently.  It is not very intuitive and easy to forget it is a binding vote even if you have enough experience to know better.

Comment: +1 I deleted an answer recently and was also confused by the voting language.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this get misinterpreted (totally understandably!) a bunch of times over the years.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Added some client side magic.

Self deletes will prompt "Delete this post?" as of the next build.