# Am I really still voting to delete my own post?

Tags: bug, tags, vote-to-delete, tooltips

I was looking about for possible duplicates of the question I was about to ask, and I found [Make it clear a self-delete vote isn't a "vote", it's just deleting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172063/make-it-clear-a-self-delete-vote-isnt-a-vote-its-just-deleting), which is *exactly* what I was about to type.

That says [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and it's from 2013, but here in 2016 I still get "vote to delete this post?"

Why is this? Surely, the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) from 2013 wasn't overturned by a later ticket, and if it was, why is that question not retagged with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)?

This question is about tooltip text for the "delete" link under the post body:

> [image: tooltip]

Comment: Given that the fix Oded mentioned involved "some client side magic", I wouldn't be surprised if it got refactored out or otherwise smashed in the last few years.

Comment: @Undo so what you're saying is I should rewrite this as a feature-request?

Comment: I'd still call it a bug. It's a regression at best, which is just a fancy word for a bug.

Comment: I don't see what you're seeing - I see ["Delete this post?"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3RLom.png) when clicking the delete link on my own questions or answers. Can you give a specific example? A screenshot and/or links to the post would be helpful.

Comment: Or... are you talking about the tooltip on the delete link instead?

Comment: @AdamLear: I think OP should be referring to the tooltip only. I've checked in SO and MSE and in both places, the popup says "Delete this post?" but the tooltip says "vote to delete this post".

Comment: @AdamLear The tooltip only, sorry