# Inconsistency between "delete" tooltip and resulting alert

Tags: feature-request, design, deleted-questions, tooltips

Hovering over the "delete" button on my own post.

[image]

Clicking the delete button.

[image]

?

I'm not voting; my own delete "vote" is automatic and definitive.

We know [the alert dialogue is like that on purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172063/make-it-clear-a-self-delete-vote-isnt-a-vote-its-just-deleting), after someone requested a wording change.
 But, the tooltip on hover didn't change to reflect the difference between self-deletion and deleting any post.

The tooltip should change to reflect the reality of the situation, and the resulting dialogue.

Comment: My original [tag:feature-request], which was badly formed to say the least: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275936/am-i-really-still-voting-to-delete-my-own-post

Comment: If we're going to mess around with this wording, I think it should also be made more clear that "deleting" a post isn't exactly deleting a post. 10k users and mods can see "deleted" posts. It's in the Help Center, but as we know, not everyone reads that.

Comment: @ThomasOwens is there a better word? "hiding?"

Comment: In the pop-up dialog: "Delete this post? It will remain visible to site moderators and users with more than 10,000 reputation on this site." I'm not sure what the effect of putting links in this dialog would be, but it would be nice to link to the relevant parts of the Help Center on deleting posts.