# Change the tooltip of "delete" link on your own post

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete, tooltips, wording

When hovering the "delete" link over my own post, I see:

> [image]

Text:

> vote to delete this post

However, when deleting my own post, the vote is binding and causes instant deletion, so the "vote" part is confusing.

Three years ago, the alert itself [was changed to "delete this post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172063/make-it-clear-a-self-delete-vote-isnt-a-vote-its-just-deleting), can the same please be done to the tooltip?

Comment: The prompt was changed to reflect the actual deletiness of the vote though http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer so it seems reasonable that the tooltip should too.

Comment: @RobertLongson  Ahh, but then we would get on a philosophical argument about whether every single deciison we make is a vote, hence we ourselves becoming a self-contained democratic institution.

Comment: You used wrong terms, which caused lots of confusion. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Nice find.

Instead of the `Vote to delete this post`, the pop-up text can be changed simply to `Delete this post`, which is simple and conveys the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are voting to delete the post. It's just that your vote is binding and immediate.

It's probably not worth the effort to check if this is your question and change the tooltip.