# Alert dialog for self-undeleting a post should be clearer: '5 votes remaining' are daily votes, and the post is insta-restored

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, undelete, original-poster, vote-to-undelete

Give that [users can self-(un)delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107497/175002) their own posts, why does the alert pop up a) say I am voting when it's instantly undeleted, and b) that there are '5 votes remaining' not a clearer message like 'You have 5 daily votes remaining?

[image: Alert dialog saying 'Vote to undelete? (5 votes remaining)']

I figured out, via [How do votes to delete work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/175002) that this is 'daily' votes, not votes on the post itself:

> "10k users" may vote to undelete deleted questions: it usually takes three votes to undelete a question [...]
> you, the author: you can undelete it
> [...] you get five votes to delete per day [...]
> You get as many votes to undelete as votes to delete.

So I don't find that dialog message clear at all.

[Make it clear a self-delete vote isn't a "vote", it's just deleting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172063/175002) is for deleting, but hasn't covered undeleting.

The mouseover is covered: [Mouseover tooltip for delete count is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233537/175002) (although the number there is *wrong* not just unclear)

But as my screen shot shows, I'm still prompted to 'vote' and told (unclearly) about 'votes remaining'?

Can that message be made clearer?

Comment: It's especially confusing because there's no limit for undeleting your own posts, and doing so on more than five posts per day will cause the counter to show a negative number. The best way to fix this is to remove the parenthetical note for users without 10k+ rep (or without 20k+ rep if the post is an answer), as that display doesn't apply to them.

Comment: @sonic what's odd is that I deleted and undeleted at least twice to get screenshots/check the behaviour.